# ZF2 Fatal console error on setTranslator

Tags: php, zend-framework2, command-line-interface, translation

My cli controller throws me an error for the translator.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend\Mvc\Router\Console\SimpleRouteStack::setTranslator() in ..
```

The function where it goes wrong

## Set route translator

```
public function onPreRoute($e)
{
    $application    = $e->getTarget();
    $serviceManager = $application->getServiceManager();
    $serviceManager->get('router')->setTranslator($serviceManager->get('translator'));
}
```

By this git issue tracker I've noticed there is a problem as it isn't compatible. My question is, how can I prevent the cli module from trying to set the translator as it throws me a Fatal error by now.

Git url: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/issues/333

Thanks

Comment: `echo \Zend\Debug\Debug::dump(get_class_methods($serviceManager->get('router')), null, false);` Shows no setTranslator method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got this problem once, because CLI request routes are not the same object as the standard Request Object (obviously)

So `Zend\Http\Request` is not equal to `Zend\Console\Request`

It's not the same module, plus, it's not event the same structure, event if they implements the same interface, some methods does not exist.

`Zend\Http\Request extends AbstractMessage`(this one extends Message)
`Zend\Console\Request extends Message` directly.

Your problem is a perfect example, we can also talk about
`$request->getUri()` wich will also not work.

To prevent that, I've a solution wich is not as elegant as I wanted to but it works. If someone has a more elegant solution please, your welcome to share it.

So the solution is :

```
if (php_sapi_name() !== 'cli' && $request->getServer('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', false)) {

// Your code that not compliant with console routes
}
```

You also can use this conditionnal statement :

```
 if (!($request instanceof \Zend\Console\Request) and !$request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
// Your code that not compliant with console routes or ajax calls
}
```

To find this solution I was inspired by the Zend skeleton application. [In their index.php](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/public/index.php) they did this :

```
if (php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server') {
    $path = realpath(__DIR__ . parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH));
    if (__FILE__ !== $path && is_file($path)) {
        return false;
    }
    unset($path);
}
```

I just see that they make some changes since my first download of it ;)